# ¿Cómo volver a la imagen anterior?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

Tengo una pantalla con una imagen y un botón, cuando le doy al botón cambio hacia la siguiente imagen, sin embargo no se como hacer para que cuando le de al botón se ponga la imagen que estaba en un principio.

Trato de hacerlo con un `if` pero me da error, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? Aquí lo que he intentado:

```
public void clickFunction(View view) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dogImage);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.perro2);

    if (ImageView == R.drawable.perro2){

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola jorge, son solo esas 2 imagenes? es decir tiene imagen1 y al pulsar cambiar por la imagen2, y al pulsar de nuevo cambiar a la 1 y así sucesivamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es usando la propiedad "Tag" para indicar mediante una cadena que recurso esta cargado.

El tag lo puedes comparar con una cadena mediante el método [setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) y asignar la imagen deseada.

Ejemplo:

```
public void clickFunction(View view) {

     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);  

     if (imageView.getTag().equals("perro"){ //Si el tag es perro carga imagen gato
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gato);
        imageView.setTag("gato");
     }else  if (imageView.getTag().equals("gato"){//Si el tag es gato carga imagen raton
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.raton);
        imageView.setTag("raton");
     } else if (imageView.getTag().equals("raton"){//Si el tag es raton carga imagen queso
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.queso);
        imageView.setTag("queso");
     }    

}
```

Otra opción obteniendo el [Drawable.ConstantState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#getConstantState()) de la imagen :

```
    Drawable.ConstantState drawableActual = circleImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState();
    Drawable.ConstantState drawableAComparar = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.perro).getConstantState();

    if(drawableActual == drawableAComparar ){           
      //Son iguales
    }else{
      //son diferentes
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar el método **getConstantState()** de drawable devuelve una instancia de **Drawable.ConstantState** que mantiene el estado compartido de este drawable.

```
if (imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.perro2).getConstantState()) {
    Toast.makeText(_con, "La imagen es perro2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.raton); // Cambiarla a otra deseada
} else {
       Toast.makeText(_con, "La imagen no es perro2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       // lo que se quieras hacer en caso que no sea igual
}
```